# SharePoint 2013 REST no permission to POST siteuser

Tags: rest, user-profile, http-headers

I am trying to POST new siteusers to `<sp_url>/_api/web/sitegroups(6)/users`.
I have managed to do so using the chrome rest client application addon.

The request contains following headers and payload:

```
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
X-RequestDigest: <formDigestValue>
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose 

{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName' : 'i:0#.w|domain\\user' }
```

Now i tried to reproduce this request on my Java Spring server using Apache httpclient:

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = initCredsProvider();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLConnectionSocketFactory())
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
HttpPost postUser = new HttpPost(sp_host + "/_api/web/sitegroups(6)/users");
postUser.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
postUser.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
postUser.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", getFormDigestValue(client));
String s = "{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName':'i:0#.w|domain\\\\user'}";
postUser.setEntity(new StringEntity(s));
HttpResponse fdvResponse = client.execute(postUser);
String response = EntityUtils.toString(fdvResponse.getEntity());
logger.info("postUserResponse" + response);
```

But I get the following error:
`Zugriff verweigert. Sie haben keine Berechtigung, diesen Vorgang auszuführen oder auf diese Ressource zuzugreifen.`
Translation: 
`Access denied . You do not have permission to perform this action or to access this resource`.

I have created several POST and GET requests like that before but never got that error.

Note: It seems like the Chrome Rest client automatically adds a few headers to the POST request:

`Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4`

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the user I was logged in with did not have permission to create new siteusers. I just gave him Admin-Rights and it worked :)