# Necessary permissions to add a new user through REST API

Tags: rest, user-profile, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to add users through the REST API, but I'm getting an authentication error.

The endpoint I'm posting the new user to is `<sp_url>/_api/web/siteusers`, using the [pnp-js-core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core) library. I get a 401, although my user has all privilages, except for admin privilages.

[This answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173724/sharepoint-2013-rest-no-permission-to-post-siteuser) mentions the fact that admin privilages resolve the issue. However, I would rather not give admin rights to every user that needs to add other users. I think it should be possible to add people through the REST API without admin privilages, as I can add users through the normal sharepoint web interface.

How can I add users through the REST API without giving the user admin privilages?

Comment: Yes, agreed to Ram answer, minimum `Manage Permission` is required in order to add/remove users from Site.

Answer (score 1):

If admin permissions cannot be given, at least 'ManagePermissions' rights are required to assign permissions to users.

Ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions.aspx